# Image slider made with JQuery slickjs not working

Tags: html, jquery, laravel-5, slick.js

Image slider is just showing the first image. The images are supposed to slide at an interval of 2000 micro seconds. The codes are mentioned blow.
    The html codes and js codes are below. Why is it now working as expected?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" 
    class="active"> 
    </li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
    <img src="images/sonevajani.jpg" alt="First Slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
    <img src="images/watervilla.jpg" alt="Second Slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
    <img src="images/centara.jpg" alt="Third Slide">
    </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" data- 
    slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span></a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" data- 
    slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span></a>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery- 
    1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery- 
    migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.js"></script>
    </body>   
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you make this into a runnable snippet? Also, pretty sure you mean milliseconds rather than micro.

Comment: Put your custom js `<script>` after `<script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.js"></script>`.

Comment: Thank you Asfan Shaikh. The JS script is now working but the image size has affected. I think it has to be solved with CSS.

Comment: 2000 microseconds is most likely unachievable.  Perhaps you meant 2000 milliseconds.